# Zend Framework 2 - I can't manage to validate form when using fieldsets

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework2, zend-form, fieldset

I have a Registration form.

```
namespace User\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;

class Register extends Form {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('register');
        $this->setAttribute('action', 'new-account');
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

        //$this->setInputFilter(new \User\Form\RegisterFilter); - used this prior to learning Fieldset
        $this->add(new \User\Form\RegisterFieldsetUser);

        // Submit
        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
                'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Register',
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

and the User fieldset:
(to make this short I've only left on field)

```
namespace User\Form;

use Zend\Form\Fieldset;

class RegisterFieldsetUser extends Fieldset {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('user');

        // User Identifier
        $identifier = new \Zend\Form\Element\Email();
        $identifier->setName('identifier');
        $identifier->setAttributes(array(
            'id' => 'user-email',
            'placeholder' => 'Email'
        ));
        $identifier->setLabel('Your email:');

        $this->add($identifier);
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
        return array(
            'identifier' => array(
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                        'break_chain_on_failure' => true,
                        'options' => array(
                            'messages' => array(
                                \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'You really have to enter something!',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'EmailAddress',
                        'options' => array(
                            'messages' => array(
                                \Zend\Validator\EmailAddress::INVALID_FORMAT => 'Hmm... this does not look valid!',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

this is my action:

```
public function registerAction() {
    $registerForm = new \User\Form\Register;

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        // Form processing
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($registerForm->isValid()) {
                // Yeeeeei
            } else {
                $registerForm->setData($formData);
                return new ViewModel(array(
                    'form' => $registerForm,
                ));
            }
    } else {
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'form' => $registerForm,
        ));
    }
}
```

Now, if I submit the form without entering anything, I get the message : "Value is required and can't be empty" (which is NOT the message I have set). But it's not an issue with the messages I set, because if I submit the form with an invalid email address ("asd/") then it doesn't say anything, no validation error. So, I assume no validation happens here.

Any clue why?
Before learning to use filedset, I had an InputFilter which worked perfectly fine, but following the book's learning curve, I got to using Fieldset.

I'm just a zf newb, learning from this book I've bought from leanpub (Michael Romer's "Web development with zf2"). I don't know the version used in the book (it was last updated in august 2013), but I use the latest (2.2.5).

Comment: I think that error message relate to `name` field, because you don't specify any validations to its value and don't point required it or not. In such cases ZF2 mark field as required, and that by-turn attaches default NotEmpty validator. And I don't think it is good idea to leave any field without any validation. At first after `'name' => ...` set array element `'required' => false` and if message disappear, then problem localized.

Comment: @Microbe I'm not sure I get what you mean by "because you don't specify any validations to...". Aren't validations specified in "getInputFilterSpecification"? Also... I didn't get where should I have put 'required' => false (is it ['identifier']['required'] => false ? in the returned array of "getInputFilterSeciffication") I've tried, no change. I also have other fields (like password field) with 'NotEmpty' and 'StringLength' with min/max validations which don't fire up. Why don't I get the same validation error ("Value is required [...]") for those other fields as well?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I wrong understood your code. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add filter specification by `getInputFilterSpecification` method your form class (or fieldset class) MUST implement InputFilterProviderInterface. So:

```
<?php

use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;

class RegisterFieldsetUser extends Fieldset
    implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I do have more fields, I've only left one to make my post here on stackoverflow shorter.
Before going "$identifier = new \Zend\Form\Element\Email(); $identifier->setName()->setAttributes() etc" I actually used the code you wrote, by the book (and switched back to it now). I've also added 'required' => false as you mentioned and showed me... I don't get "Value is required and can't be empty" anymore... but still no other validation happens. If I submit the empty form or form with invalid data (shorter password), the $registerForm->isValid() returns true.

Comment: Yap... this solves it. Guess the book needs some updating here and there...
Thank you!

I can click the check mark by your answer (which I did) but I'm not allowed to vote up yet. Thanks again!

Comment: I check the book and there is all ok.

Comment: My sample comes from page 181 of the book (modified to my needs, based on the small zf2 project I chose to start instead of literally following the code in the book). There, the fieldset class doesn't implement InputFilterProviderInterface. I've just re-downloaded the book (just to make sure, even though it's not updated since august, when I believed it was finished). Otherwise, a great book. There aren't many resources out there teaching zf2 that start from the "newb level". There's one more (Using zf2) but for the db part it's focused on Doctrine (I want "plain" zf2), plus it's not finished.